# Stroke order of 濃

Tags: stroke-order

What is the correct stroke order to write this kanji 濃 in Japanese? How many strokes will it have and in what correct order. Assume a japanese writing exam situation.

Also does anyone have a picture of a handwriting  example of this particular kanji handwritten just using common regular pen that could be considered by Japanese goverment officials and also Japanese people in common, as a good and correct example of the handwriting of this kanji? For non-cursive (regular but handwritten), semi cursive and cursive style. (not a picture of one written using printing or fountain pen or brush).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stroke order is:

[image]

For future reference, this is easily Googleable.  See [kakijun.com](http://kakijun.com/) as a resource.

For the second part of your question, I don't think there's a "standard" by the government―let alone by everyday people―for what is considered readable.  If they can read it, then it's readable.

Comment: I would like to know how is it supposed to look like in an actual handwritting just using regular pen (not fountain pen or brush and not a digital one of course) in all three styles (in Chinese language there are non-cursive, semicursive and cursive styles, I don't know if in Japanese language they use semicursive handwriting style as often?). As for the part where I said "readable", just ignore it. If it is the "correct" way to handwrite it, then it should be readable!

Comment: What's posted above doesn't count as a handwritten form?

Comment: I found one [here] (http://www.yamasa.cc/ocjs/kanjidic.nsf/SortedByKanji2THEnglish/%E6%BF%83?OpenDocument), but there is no information as to whether this is semi cursive or cursive.

Comment: [https://www.reddit.com/r/PenmanshipPorn/comments/9kzhzc/japanese_semicursive/] (This) one is a great example thought the kanji i'm looking for is not there.

Comment: Gezzz why won't the mini markdown formatting work

Comment: @leebo That would count...as a noncursive style

Comment: @Tomsofty33 what about a site like this https://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E6%BF%83/page.html

Comment: @Leebo ..That's a great addition ..how do.you explore that site, i mean to find the one using regular pen? I mean it's all Japanese.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 me personally? I can read all the Japanese. If you can't, then I suppose you'd have to start by translating all the labels.

Comment: But looking at the various displayed images of handwritten 濃 over  there, which one did you mean exactly that uses regular pen in that site?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 Well, one is specifically labeled ペン字体, but others could have been written with pen as well.

Comment: http://www.yamasa.cc/ocjs/kanjidic.nsf/SortedByKanji2THEnglish/%E6%BF%83?OpenDocument in the link I quoted Before this comment it wasn't even labeled what style it was, but I can definitely tell that was created using regular pen. The one you mentioned was labeled as pen font (ペン字体),  but just by looking at it, I know that I definitely cannot imitate that by just using regular pen. Perhaps a pen with a brushed tip..or a marker

Comment: @Tomsofty33 what is a "regular pen?" You can definitely do ペン字 without a brush pen. Anyway, this isn't the place to discuss this.

Comment: The examples of what I'm looking for are posted on those links..If you're unclear about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96779/discussion-between-leebo-and-tomsofty33).